# Changing a Dictionary in a List of a List in Python

Tags: python

Sorry if this is a basic Python question, but for some reason, I can't figure this out.

Suppose I create a list of a list of a dictionary,

```
b=[[{'j':1}]*3]*3
```

so that "b" is this:

```
[[{'j': 1}, {'j': 1}, {'j': 1}],
[{'j': 1}, {'j': 1}, {'j': 1}],
[{'j': 1}, {'j': 1}, {'j': 1}]]
```

Now suppose I want to change "b" to:

```
[[{'j': 1}, {'j': 1}, {'j': 1}],
[{'j': 1}, {'j': 1}, {'j': 90}],
[{'j': 1}, {'j': 1}, {'j': 1}]]
```

so I naively use this line of code

```
b[1][2]['j']=90
```

However, "b" is now this:

```
[[{'j': 90}, {'j': 90}, {'j': 90}],
[{'j': 90}, {'j': 90}, {'j': 90}],
[{'j': 90}, {'j': 90}, {'j': 90}]]
```

Why did all of the dictionaries in the list of a list change?  Why didn't only the b[1][2] entry change?

Also, the lines

```
b=[[{'j':1}]*3]*3
b[1][2]={'j':90}
```

changes "b" to

```
[[{'j': 1}, {'j': 1}, {'j': 90}],
[{'j': 1}, {'j': 1}, {'j': 90}],
[{'j': 1}, {'j': 1}, {'j': 90}]]
```

which I also can't explain.

Comment: Ah! I see!  Thanks for the amazingly quick reply.  That is exactly what I needed.

Comment: please read this http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the dictionary's `copy()` command, or else you are creating multiple references to the same dictionary.

Try something like this:

```
>>> c = {'j':1}
>>> b = [c, c.copy(), c.copy()]
>>> b
[{'j': 1}, {'j': 1}, {'j': 1}]
>>> b[2]['j']=2
>>> b
[{'j': 1}, {'j': 1}, {'j': 2}]
```